# Two inserts in one trigger casues the second insert to fail

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I have a triggerHandler on the Opportunity object which inserts other objects on afterInsert if it meets the criteria (Opportunity Line Item and Payment). The objects are added to a list before inserting but when the first list is inserted the next list is emptied/nulled so nothing is being inserted on the next list.

The instantiation of the lists looks like this:

```
static List<Membership__c> membershipsToUpdate;
static List<Case> casesToUpdate;
static List<OpportunityLineItem> oppItemsToInsert;
static List<npe01__OppPayment__c> paymentsToInsert;

public TRG_OpportunityHandler(){
    membershipsToUpdate = new List<Membership__c>();
    casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
    oppItemsToInsert = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    paymentsToInsert = new List<npe01__OppPayment__c>();
}
```

And the inserts look like this:

```
  if(paymentsToInsert.size() > 0) {
        insert paymentsToInsert;
    }
    if(oppItemsToInsert.size() > 0) {
        insert oppItemsToInsert;
    }
    if(membershipsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update membershipsToUpdate;
    }
    if(casesToUpdate.size() > 0 ){
        update casesToUpdate;
    }
```

If I switch place and insert oppItemsToInsert before paymentsToInsert then oppItems are inserted but not payments. Is it really not possible to do 2 DML transactions in one trigger? How else can I do this?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing as many DML statements as the Governor allows, multiple inserts are absolutely common. If the snippets you gave are all that is happening to the lists, then it should work. Any error messages?

Comment: There are no errors. The lists just goes blank. I just noticed that both the lists go blank after the first DML statement.

Here is a screenshot of the logs when debuggging both lists before and after each insert transaction: http://prntscr.com/oxnuhp

Comment: Ok I just noticed the problem looking at my own debug logs from the screenshot. Opportunity update is run which causes the list to be reistantiated in the constructor which resets the list.

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say what is happening. How do the `oppItemsToInsert` and `paymentsToInsert` get filled? We've seen part of your trigger handler, but what does the trigger itself look like?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the instantiation from the constructor of the handler to inside the afterInsert trigger method solved it. Since the trigger was firing again with an update it reinstatiated the lists and nulled them: http://prntscr.com/oxnuhp